# Replace multiple instances of an object with single instance in a graph of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext

**[UPDATED]**

I'm using `EF code first` and in my case I have to disconnect my `POCO`s from `DbContext`, and when I want to save back changes to `DB`, attach disconnected `POCO`s(by attaching root object) to `DbContex`t, but in my graph of objects that want to save, may be multiple instance of an entity with the same key.
For examle:

```
Order1
|
OrderLine1-->Product1 //instance1 of product1
|
OrderLine2-->Product1 //instance2 of product1
```

So I get following error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

So I want write a method that find and replace duplicate instances of an object with one instance in my `ApplyChange()` method:

```
public void ApplyChanges<TEntity>(TEntity root) where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
        _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(root);
        foreach (var entry in _dbContext.ChangeTracker
        .Entries<BaseEntity>())
        {
            if (FoundAnEntityWithSameKeyInDbContext<TEntity>(entry))
                UniqeSimilarEntities(entry);
            else
            {
              ....  
            }
        }
}
```

I wrote this piece of code:

```
private bool FoundAnEntityWithSameKeyInDbContext<TEntity>(DbEntityEntry<BaseEntity> entry) where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
        var tmp = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>().Count(t => t.Entity.Id == entry.Entity.Id && t.Entity.Id != 0 && t.Entity.GetType() == entry.Entity.GetType());
        if (tmp > 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
private void UniqeSimilarEntities(DbEntityEntry<BaseEntity> entry)
{
        var similarEntities = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>()
        .Where(
            t =>
                t.Entity.Id == entry.Entity.Id && t.Entity.Id != 0 &&
                t.Entity.GetType() == entry.Entity.GetType()).ToList();

        for (int i = 1; i < similarEntities.Count; i++)
        {
          _dbContext.Entry(similarEntities[i]).CurrentValues.SetValues(similarEntities[0]);
            similarEntities[i].State= EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
}
```

All my entities Inherited from a `BaseEntity` class:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public States State { get; set; }
  public bool MustDelete {get; set;} 
  ... 
}
```

But when control reaches to `UniqeSimilarEntities` method line `_dbContext.Entry(similarEntities[i]).CurrentValues.SetValues...` I get this error:

> The entity type DbEntityEntry`1 is not part of the model for the current context.

Is there any way to replace duplicate entities with one instance in my root object?

Answer (score 0):

Imho you should unduplicate before attachement. In pseudo code:

```
List<Product> lp = new List<Product>();
foreach (var line in Order.Lines) {
    Product p = lp.Where(x => x.Id == line.Product.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if ( p == null ) {
        lp.Add(p);
    } else {
       line.Product = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Order,OrderLine,Product was an example, I want to unduplicate objects in my root object(that it is an object that inherited from BaseEntity).I updated the post.